# Arduino not receiving Bluetooth GATT signal

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno, bluetooth-gatt

On my android studio app, I have a button that when pressed, sends a "go" signal and on release sends a "stop" signal.

When you hold the button down and then release it works fine with the Arduino receiving both signals. However, when it is a quick tap, the Arduino does not receive the stop signal.

I have checked that the signal is in fact being sent as I put a log message whenever this happens so it must be a problem with the Arduino not the app not detecting button presses.

Here is the code:

```
ImageButton fwdBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fwd);
fwdBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                view.performClick();
                sendSignal("fwd");
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                sendSignal("stop");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

private void sendSignal(String signal) {
    if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, 101)) {
        // Commands is a dictionary for converting string commands to integers 
        msg.setValue(commands.get(signal));
        gatt.beginReliableWrite();
        gatt.writeCharacteristic(msg);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have since realised that the gatt.writeCharacteristic(msg) is returning false. I tried to fix it by doing a while loop constantly running writeCharacteristic  until it returned true and it only partially fixed it. Tapping it quickly once is no longer problematic. However when you spam it 5 or 6 times the problem comes back. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would assume that you sent the second message before the first send operation was finished. BLE is synchronous, so you can only send one message at a time.

Comment: Android detects various gestures. I mean motion events. Sometimes when a finger moved away from the pressed view, a **CANCEL** action is sent to `onTouch`. You should check what actions your `onTouch` implementation receives more.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan is there a way I can detect easily if the initial "go" signal was received or would I have to make the Arduino send a signal back saying it was received?

Comment: @fireguy187 Try implementing the [onCharacteristicWrite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20int)) callback